# PyInstaller (ImportError: cannot import name 'jwt' from 'jwcrypto') (SOLVED)

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.7, executable

Good morning.

I have an application in **Python 3.7** which uses several libraries and files that has the following structure:

```
app2:
  - Blockchain
  - db
  - secrets
  - smartcontrats
  - utils
  - menu.py
```

At this moment my application is running without problems and I need to generate an executable for linux, but first I want to generate it in one-folder and when this is worked, generate the one-file executable. I have read the manual of **PyInstaller** and tried small examples to see how it works. The problem is when I tried to do the same with my application.

This is the command that I´m using to generate it:

> pyinstaller --clean --noconfirm --onedir --log-level=ERROR "./menu.py" --add-data "./blockchain:blockchain/" --add-data "./db:db/" --add-data "./secrets:secrets/" --add-data "./smartcontracts:smartcontracts/" --add-data "./utils:utils/" --hidden-import uuid --hidden-import "web3" --hidden-import "sqlite3" --hidden-import "jwcrypto" --hidden-import "jwcrypto.jwk" --hidden-import "pydantic"

This creates "dist" folder with libs, codes without errors and when I execute the "menu" inside "dist" folder, I have the next error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "app2/menu.py", line 2, in 
> File "/home/user/Desktop/app2/dist/menu/blockchain/canismajor.py", line 9, in 
> from blockchain import wallet
> File "/home/user/Desktop/app2/dist/menu/blockchain/wallet.py", line 11, in 
> from jwcrypto import jwt, jwk, jws
> **ImportError: cannot import name 'jwt' from 'jwcrypto'**(/home/user/Desktop/app2/dist/menu/jwcrypto/**init**.pyc)
> [66099] Failed to execute script 'menu' due to unhandled exception!

I have reinstalled "jwt", add it to "--hidden-import", check all versions but I can't fix the error and get it to work.

Comment: I have removed jwcrypto to me application and now I can generate the executable.